# How to create a SP List from a SP List template with Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate

How can I create a Sharepoint list from a Sharepoint list template with Power Automate?

This below is what I got so far. But how can I specify the list template?

[image]

Comment: It seems that creating a list based on list template using SharePoint REST API is not possible. Check [this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/37608703-add-support-to-create-list-document-library-base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can create a SharePoint List using the "send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action:

[image]

**Uri**

_api/web/lists

**HTTP Action parameters**

- Method: POST

**Headers**

- content-type: application/json;odata=verbose

**Body**

```
{
    "__metadata":{"type":"SP.List"},
    "AllowContentTypes":false,
    "BaseTemplate":100,
    "ContentTypesEnabled":false,
    "Description":"",
    "Title":"New List Title"
}
```

**Update**

I missed the part of the question asking about templates. The answer is that you can't create lists from a template using REST.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that creating a SharePoint list based on "custom list template" using SharePoint REST API is not possible.

> In REST it is possible just to pass `ListTemplateTypeKind` as `BaseTemplate` parameter and there is **no parameter for custom template name** so it is not possible to create new list/library based on custom template.

**Reference**:

1. [How to work with custom list templates via REST API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-to-work-with-custom-list-templates-via-rest-api/m-p/7965)
2. [Add support to create list / document library based on custom template to REST API](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/37608703-add-support-to-create-list-document-library-base)